# Speed up pandas dataframe iteration

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe with date and values,

```
 Date     Price
Jun 30    95.60
Jun 29    94.40
Jun 28    93.59
Jun 27    92.04
Jun 24    93.40
Jun 23    96.10
Jun 22    95.55
Jun 21    95.91
Jun 20    95.10
Jun 17    95.33
Jun 16    97.55
Jun 15    97.14
Jun 14    97.46
Jun 13    97.34
Jun 10    98.83
Jun 9     99.65
Jun 8     98.94
Jun 7     99.03
Jun 6     98.63
Jun 3     97.92
Jun 2     97.72
```

There is a function which iterate through dateframe,

```
indic_up = [False, False,False, False]
i = 4
while i+4 <= df.index[-1]:
    if (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-1, 'value')) or
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-2, 'value')) or
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-3, 'value')) or
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-4, 'value')):indic_up.append(True)
    else:indic_up.append(False)
    i = i+1
```

The logic of this function is if `value` of today greater than yesterday,day before yesterday or before that then it's `true` or `false`.
This functions seems to be very slow to me, So how i can rewrite this function like these

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
row['a'], index
```

or

```
for idx in df.index:
df.ix[idx, 'a'], idx
```

or can i achieve more fast by converting dataframe into numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's invite `Scipy` too!

**The Idea :** Compare the current element with the previous `4` values by calculating the minimum in that interval and comparing with the current one. If it matches, we have basically failed all the comparisons and thus choose `False`. So, codewise, just compare the current element with the minimum in that interval. This is where `scipy` comes in with its [`minimum_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter.html).

**Implementation :**

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import minimum_filter

# Extract values from relevant column into a NumPy array for further procesing
A = df['value'].values

# Look for no match with interval-ed min & look for NOT matching for True as o/p
indic_up_out = A != minimum_filter(A,footprint=np.ones((5,)),origin=2)

# Set first four as False because those would be invalid with a 5 elem runway
indic_up_out[:4] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually *time it*. Here is my experiment. It shows that loop over an list is much faster than your method. The answer from @Divakar is actually very good.

```
import pandas as pd
import timeit
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['Jun 30', 'Jun 29', 'Jun 28', 'Jun 27', 'Jun 24', 'Jun 23', 'Jun 22', 'Jun 21', 'Jun 20', 'Jun 17', 
                        'Jun 16','Jun 15', 'Jun 14', 'Jun 13', 'Jun 10', 'Jun 9', 'Jun 8', 'Jun 7', 'Jun 6', 'Jun 3', 'Jun 2'], 
            'value': ['95.60', '94.40', '93.59', '92.04', '93.40', '96.10', '95.55', '95.91', '95.10', '95.33', '97.55', 
                        '97.14', '97.46', '97.34', '98.83', '99.65', '98.94', '99.03', '98.63', '97.92', '97.72']})


def by_df_get_value():
    indic_up = [False, False,False, False]
    i = 4
    while i+4 <= df.index[-1]:
        if (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-1, 'value')) or \
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-2, 'value')) or \
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-3, 'value')) or \
        (df.get_value(i, 'value') > df.get_value(i-4, 'value')):

        indic_up.append(True)
    else:
        indic_up.append(False)
    i = i+1


def by_list():
    indic_up = [False, False,False, False]
    values = df['value'].tolist()
    for i, v in enumerate(values):
        if i < 4:
            continue
        if (v > values[i-1]) or \
            (v > values[i-2]) or \
            (v > values[i-3]) or \
            (v > values[i-4]):
            indic_up.append(True)
        else:
            indic_up.append(False)

total_time = []
for i in range(10):
    t = timeit.Timer('by_df_get_value()','from __main__ import by_df_get_value').timeit(number=1)
    total_time.append(t)
print('by_df_get_value(): ', '{:.20f}'.format(np.mean(total_time)))


total_time = []
for i in range(10):
    t = timeit.Timer('by_list()','from __main__ import by_list').timeit(number=1)
    total_time.append(t)
print('by_list', '{:.20f}'.format(np.mean(total_time)))
```

Here is output on my machine:

```
by_df_get_value():  0.00015220100467558951
by_list():  0.00002649170055519790
```